# Instantiating an Inherited class from a string

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to instantiate an inherited object (knowing the class name).

Assuming I have

```
public abstract Monster{
    public string name;
    public string specie;
    public Stats baseStats;
    public string imgDir;
}
```

and

```
public Specie1 : Monster{
    public new string specie = "Specie1";
    public new Stats baseStats = {1,2,3,4,5};
    public new imgDir = "dir/specie1.png";
    public Specie1(string n){
        name = n;
    }
}
```

My objective is to load from saved file the monsters, testing it with only one specie, I do the following:

```
Monster[0] = new Specie1("foo");
```

But in the event that I have many species, is there a way to instantiate generically?

For example:

```
string specie = loadSpecie();
Monster[] = new specie("foo");
```

I am hoping there is a way to do this without creating a lot of switches and ifs everywhere.

I was thinking of creating a constructor

```
Monster(string species,string name){
    if(species == "Specie1"){
        return new Specie1(name);
    }
}
```

But I think that would be horrible programming, and not scalable at all.

Comment: Is your derived classes only setting different values to the variables? In that case just make multiple instances of your Monster class and set the properties...

Comment: This is a prime candidate for a generic factory method.

Comment: Is what you mean by generically, polymorphic ?

Comment: On a side note, you might consider making Monster an interface rather than a class. As long as you never need to instantiate a generic "Monster" (i.e. not one of the derived classes) it would be better practice.

Comment: @LeandroLibarona I rolled your question back to its original state. Since the question has a marked answer, there is no need to include the solution in your question. Those looking in the future will see the marked answer and see the solution. We want to keep the question itself clean and easy to read for those looking for solutions to problems matching theirs in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a factory method to instance the monster sub-classes.

```
public abstract Monster
{
    public string name;
    public string specie;
    public Stats baseStats;
    public string imgDir;

    public static Monster CreateMonster(string monster)
    {
        Type[] types = GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetTypes();
        Type monsterType = types.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.ToLower().Equals(monster.ToLower()));

        if (monsterType == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The given monster does not have a Type associated with it.");

        return Activator.CreateInstance(monsterType) as Monster;
    }
}

public class Cat : Monster
{
}
```

The `CreateMonster` method looks up all of the types in the current assembly and creates an instance of the first Type it finds that has a name that matches the monster name provided. You would probably want to include some logic so that it doesn't try to instance an abstract class, and ensure the type is actually a child class of `Monster.`

Personally I would probably decorate the monster sub-classes with an attribute that gives a friendly name to each class. I would save the attribute value to the file, and to the first Type that has an attribute matching the monster name. I would also only do the `GetTypes()` call once. You should cache the result in a private static field in the Monster class. This way, you only use reflection once. In any event, the above code works and can be used like this:

```
Monster cat = Monster.CreateMonster("Cat");
```

Comment: Excelent!!!
with almost no modifications I've got this running smoothly on unity3d!